# how to concatenate two items as one and search from drop down in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a database having records and i am searching them from my asp.net web form behind a button but there are two items named as Appliances and i have bind all the items on my drop down in asp.net web form but the thing i want to do is i don't want both the appliances to be displayed, i want them to be displayed as one and when i will select that appliances from my drop down and click on search button then the data should come from both the appliances, is this possible??

Comment: wait, appliances is the name or appliance has many records or just a single row?

Comment: i have appliances as a category and i have an ID of appliance in another table as foreign key from where i will select all the data but my problem is that how to make them display as one

Comment: Please add some code here

Comment: i have bind my drop down from two tables and two tables has a same name as appliance, i hided one item name appliance, now i want if i click on appliance from my drop down the data should be displayed from two tables is this possible?

Comment: Create a model/class which contains all the fields you need. Populate the model  from as many tables as you want and pass the model data to the dropdown.